# Should I ever directly call object.__str__()?

Tags: python, oop

I'm writing a class in Python and I'm writing a `__str__()` function so my print statements can print string representations of instances of that class. Is there ever a reason to directly do something like this:

```
myObj = Foo(params)
doSomething(myObj.__str__())
```

It feels like since there are other neater ways to do this, it would be a bad idea (or at least, not proper style) to directly call `__str__()`. That said, I can't find a website specifically saying not to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, dunder methods define how an object behaves in a particular context. They aren't intended to be used directly. (The major exception being when you are overriding a dunder method inherited from a parent class.)

In the case of `__str__`, there are [three documented uses](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__); it is used by the built-in functions `str`, `format`, and `print` so that (roughly speaking)

1. `str(myObj) == myObj.__str__()`
2. `format("{}", myObj) == format("{}", myObj.__str__())`
3. `print(myObj) == print(myObj.__str__())`.

The key here is that `__str__` allows code that *isn't* built-in to Python to work with these functions; the `__str__` method provides the common interface all three can use.

Answer (score 3):

```
myObj.__str__()
```

is the same as

```
str(myObj)
```

unless someone has the bad idea to hide `str` built-in by reassigning its name:

```
str = lambda x: None
```

in which case only the first approach would work. But in the general case, it's better to avoid calling those dunder methods directly.

Comment: It's a bad idea, but a very common thing to do, since `str` is the most common name for a string variable, and causes a very hard to detect bug.

Comment: yes. Bad idea. Python experienced coders don't do that mistake :) you can extend the example to `list` and `dict`...

Comment: *any mistake ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a custom string representation of your class, implement `__str__` in your class definition, and then you can call it using `str(myObj)` which will call your method. Calling `__str__` will be the same, but isn't as clean I'd say.