# What is the purpose of the python builtin vars() function?

Tags: python

I find the documentation on the vars() function to be kind of cryptic: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars

What is the point of having this function? Why would you not just call `x.__dict__` rather than `vars(x)` or `locals()` directly?

Would someone give a use case of the function?

Answer (score 8):

The point of having the `vars()` function is:

- you do not need to touch the classes `__dict__` dunder function directly from the outside

It is the same with most `__dunders__`:

```
next()  => __next__  
>=      => __ge__
<=      => __le__
str()   => __str__
repr()  => __repr__
```

See:  [Python datamodel `__lt__` etc.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__)

See also: [Should I ever directly call object.__str__()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49696701/should-i-ever-directly-call-object)

Comment: it's focus on more readable and clean code right ?

Comment: @prashantrana  and encapsulation. The "normal" methods can have logic that calling the dunder directly would not have

Comment: @PatrickArtner could you give an example of this type of logic? It seems here that vars() doesn't have any additional logic?

Comment: @AllenWang wait for python 3.7 / 3.8  ... maybe it will have it then - maybe some other dunder gets introduced that i also checked by next() as fallback - if you cann `__dict__` directly you wont get that added functionality

Answer (score 0):

The python builtin `vars(object)` function returns the `__dict__` attribute of the object in the parentheses; if not applicable, it gives a `TypeError` exception. It should be used to view dictionaries.

When you run:

```
# Python program to illustrate 
# working of vars() method in Python 

class Example: 
def __init__(self, name1 = "Bob", num2 = 100, name3 = "Bill"): 
    self.name1 = name1 
    self.num2 = num2 
    self.name3 = name3 

exampleVariable = Example()
print(vars(exampleVariable))
```

The output is:

```
{'num2': 100, 'name1': 'Bob', 'name3': 'Bill'}
```

Comment: I feel that using vars(x) is more trustworthy and reliable than other solutions that can do the same thing.